# JAVA implementation SQLJ Stored Procedure using DB2 for IBM i (AS400)

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, sqlj

I tried to create a stored procedure in SQLJ using IBM data studio and able to create the three types of files on building as xxx.class, xxx_Profile0.ser and xxx_ProfileKeys.class and placed the (.class) files in the below directory /QIBM/UserData/OS400/SQLLib/Function.

Created the stored procedure as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE XXXX.SQLJ_JAVA ( ) 
    LANGUAGE JAVA 
    SPECIFIC XXXX.SQLJ_JAVA 
    NOT DETERMINISTIC 
    NO SQL 
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
    EXTERNAL NAME 'sample.execution' 
    PARAMETER STYLE DB2GENERAL ;
```

While executing the procedure getting the exception below.

> SQL State: 42724
>   Vendor Code: -4304
>   Message: [SQL4304]  Java stored procedure or user-defined function SQLJ_JAVA, specific name SQLJ_JAVA could not load Java class SP for reason code 1.

Let me know if any thing goes wrong.

Comment: What you specify in the `EXTERNAL NAME` clause must match the actual class and method name.

Comment: yes I did that same.